# Description of what an interface does?

Tags: oop, interface

With regards to OOP, how would you describe an interface?

What I mean is, sub-classing can be described as *"Has-A"*, and inheritance could be *"Is-A"*. A member method could be *"Can-Do"*.

Is there any way this could be extended (no pun intended) to describe what an interface does?

Comment: composition can be described as "has-a", not subclassing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think of objects as **nouns**, methods as **verbs**, and interfaces as **adjectives** (of course this analogy is oversimplified, but frequently works well enough).

Example:  an interface `Serializable` works like an adjective, in that it applies some qualities to an object that implement that interface, but does not change what that object is.  We can say, "this is a serializable object."  But we don't say, "this object *is a* serializable," nor do we say, "this object *has a* serializable."

I also like Federico's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394260/description-of-what-an-interface-does#394275) that an interface is "CAN-DO".

An interface is a group of related operations that the class supports.  Together, the methods in an interface describe what the class can do.

Just like a noun can take multiple adjectives, a class can implement multiple interfaces, as long as they don't conflict.  The union of all the interfaces a class implements is the sum of what the class can do.

In practical terms, an interface is a set of method signatures, without the code implementing those methods.  Just the method name and arguments.  Depending on the language, a method signature may also include return type, and exceptions thrown.

An interface consists of methods, but not data members.

BTW, I wouldn't say sub-classing is HAS-A.  My understanding is that sub-classing is the same as inheritance, so these are both IS-A.  Whereas HAS-A is called Aggregation or Composition.

- **Composition** is where an object owns another object.  Destroying the outer object also destroys the inner objects.  Example:  University composes Departments.  Close the University, and the Departments disappear.
- **Aggregation** is where an object includes another object, but does not own it.  Destroying the outer object does not destroy the inner objects.  Example:  University employs Professors, but closing the University does not kill the Professors.

Answer (score 2):

An interface is an abstract base class with all pure virtual members.

So looking at your Has-A/Is-A, it should be similar to whatever you would be apply for an abstract base class.

Interfaces generally exist in languages that do not fully support multiple inheritance as a way to more safely offer some of the same benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Acts-As-A.

Answer (score 1):

As is your description for methods, I would also describe an interface as a "Can-Do". An interface is a *contract* like "all the classes that implement me, can do these things".

Answer (score 0):

Joel that isn't exaclty what an interface is. It is like a abstract base class in a way but it has no implementation of the methods and properties.

This pretty much sums up what an interface is.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_interrfaces03052006095933AM/csharp_interrfaces.aspx?ArticleID=cd6a6952-530a-4250-a6d7-54717ef3b345

Comment: Hence the "all pure-virtual members" part.